# Jquery.ajax POST call running wrong method supplied

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, post

I am trying to run an action method from a jQuery.ajax call but what I am seeing is that the controller name POST method "Edit" is being run instead of the action I am supplying in the url attribute "DeleteItem"

Client

```
 $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Edit/DeleteItem?id=1',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function () {
            alert('Deleted OK');
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {

            alert(thrownError);
        },

});
```

Server code

```
    // I expect it to be running this
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult DeleteItem(string id)
    {
        return Json(""); 
    }

    // And not this
    [HttpPost]
    [Authorize]
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public ActionResult Edit(ViewModel)
    {
        try
          ....
```

Route config

```
    routes.MapRoute(
    "Edit", // Route name
    "Edit/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Edit", action = "Edit", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Is there anything I have done wrong in the JQuery.ajax method?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the route config you posted, all your routes will go to the `Edit` action. You need to make the action configurable per URL. Try this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
"Edit", // Route name
"Edit/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
new { controller = "Edit", action = "Edit", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Your actions will then be available at:

```
// Edit:
http://localhost:63672/Edit/Edit

// Delete:
http://localhost:63672/Edit/DeleteItem
```

Comment: Thank you, when you mentioned routing above, it clicked. WIll mark as correct when SO lets me